# Java, Integers not unique but how are they compared in collections?

Tags: java, collections, autoboxing

I used this straight-forward method:

```
    Collection<Integer> aCollection = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    Integer a = new Integer(5);

    if( aCollection.contains(a) )
        System.out.println("aCollection contains 5");
```

Result is "aCollection contains 5". Integers are not unique objects in whole system, but in this case are the "5" in `Collection<Integer>` and the `new Integer(5)` in fact references to the same object?
Can I safely assume that any collection will behave this way when calling `.contains()`?

I am not sure because when comparing references and values by `==` result is:

```
3 == new Integer(3)
new Integer(3) != new Integer(3)
new Integer(3) == 3
```

Comment: You can solve these kind of doubts, just by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in [**JavaDoc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

> Returns `true` if this collection contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns `true` if and only if this collection contains at
>   least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

In words: If `o` is `null`, contains will return `true` if the collection contains a `null` element, otherwise it will return `true` if and only if there is an element that `equals()` the one you are searching for.

Every call to `new Integer(5)` will return a different reference, but all the objects are equal to one another according to the [`equals()` method of the `Integer` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Compares this object to the specified object. The result is `true` if
>   and only if the argument is not `null` and is an `Integer` object that
>   contains the same `int` value as this object.

Comment: OK, new Integer(3) != new Integer(3), and (new Integer(3)).equals( new Integer(3) ). Collection compares with equals.

Answer (score 5):

`contains` does not compare by reference. `new Integer(50000)` is different from another call to `new Integer(50000)`. However, `firstInt.equals(new Integer(50000))` will return true, hence contains will work. I use higher numbers since interning can happen with lower ones.

0-127 will be put into a fixed pool when performing boxing *but not when explicitly creating new objects* so you'll have the same reference to the same value, but above that, you have no guarantee of any interning, and references may be to different Integer objects for the same value. `Integer.valueOf(` will attempt to intern where appropriate, namely always within `[-128, 128)` and with no specification for or against interning outside this range.

> Can I safely assume that any collection will behave this way when calling `.contains()`?

You can assume that `.contains(Object o)` will return `true` *if and only if* one or more members of the collection satisfies `thatmember.equals(o)`, or if `o` is null, and there is at least one `null` member.

Technically:

> Returns `true` if this collection contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns `true` if and only if this collection contains at
>   least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Comment: "_0-127 will be put into a fixed pool so you'll have the same reference to the same value..._" Not when you explicitly call `new Integer(5)`.

Comment: @jlordo "but above that, you have no guarantee of any interning, and references may be different." Better now?

Comment: I've edited my comment, it's not correct yet. You have a contradiction: "_0-127 will be put into a fixed pool so you'll have the same reference to the same value ... and references may be different._"

Comment: @jlordo I may be missing something, but I don't see the contradiction. For 0-127, interning occurs and references are the same. Above that, the references point to different objects for the same value.

Comment: As said in my first comment. When you **explicitly** call `new Integer(5)` you'll get a reference to a new object, not the interned one.

Comment: @jlordo Oh, I missed what you were talking about. Understood now.

Comment: Check JavaDoc of [`new Integer(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer(int)) and [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))

Answer (score 0):

`.contains()` of an collection calls the `.equals()` method internally.

In your case you are using an Integer object. And an Integer object .equals() might return true in all the cases you have listed.

However that might not be case for a custom object you have say Person.

Now for a collection

```
Collection<Person> aCollection = Arrays.asList(b,c,d);
    Person a = new Person("Abhishek");
```

may return false. because you have not overridden the .equals() method in your Person class

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html